# Pass Ruby JSON variable to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have created index.html.erb file and had ruby/html code in it and file is running on webrick server at localhost **without using rails** .

I have a Global JSON variable in my Ruby code. It looks like this :

`@ruby_side_json = [{ :name => 'Will', :age => 23 },{ :name => 'John', :age => 30 }].to_json`

I want this to be assigned to my javascript variable which resides in script

Not succeed by writing : `var javascript_side_json = <%= @ruby_side_json %>`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: what do you see in browser console, when you type `javascript_side_json`?

Comment: [Object{ :name => 'Will', :age => 23 },Object{ :name => 'John', :age => 30 }]

Comment: Try.. var javascript_side_json = JSON.parse(<%= @rails_side_json %>);

Comment: Without rails? Then try require 'json'; and @rails_side_json.to_json.  What is the error that u r getting?

Comment: In general, instead of using inline javascript, you might want to pass the json to some meta-tag / data attribute, e.g. in your application layout  <meta js-side-json="<%= @rails_side_json %>">.

There is also a gem called gon https://github.com/gazay/gon which does essentially the same but via a more convenient api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using rails tag inside script tag, it should be quoted with single or double quotes.

Change your code as given below :

var javascript_side_json = '<%= @rails_side_json %>';

Answer (score 0):

In the environment you describe, the only way I can see that working, is by creating a `<script>` tag directly in the html and rendering it at the top, before any javascript require tags.

like this:

```
<head>
  <script>
    var javascript_side_json = <%= @rails_side_json %>
  </script>
</head>
```

That said, it's kinda ugly, but it should work; if you don't place it before the JS require tags, then the data won't be there when you try to execute some JS that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're not using Rails, and JSON is being generated properly with your `to_json` implementation. Then try doing this:

```
<script>    
  var javascript_side_json = <%= @rails_side_json %>;
</script>
```